# Android ListView with custom layout getCheckedItemPositions

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, baseadapter

I have a `ListView` with custom layout with `CheckBox` to select multiple items to delete but `list.getCheckedItemPositions()` always returns 0.

I can't find out what I am missing. How can I populate checked item list when user checks a `CheckBox` to true so that `getCheckedItemPositions` returns them?

**listview**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adViewHolder" />
```

**row**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/recording_play_holder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recording_play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/multi_checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter**

```
public RecordingsAdapter(Context context, ListActivity a, ArrayList<MyObject> items) {
    mContext = context;
    mItems = items;
    mActivity = a;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    checkBoxState=new boolean[items.size()];

 }
 ..................
 ................
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View vi = convertView;
     if(convertView==null) {
         vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recording_list_item, null);
     }   

     final CheckBox multi_checkBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById      (R.id.multi_checkBox);
     multi_checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
     multi_checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
             if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
                 checkBoxState[position]=true;                  
                 v.setSelected(true);                   
             } else{
                 checkBoxState[position]=false;
                 v.setSelected(false);
             }            
         }
    });

    return vi;

}
```

**activity**

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = list.getCheckedItemPositions();  
Log.i("recorded_file_delete list.getCheckedItemPositions()", String.valueOf(list.getCheckedItemPositions().size())); 
int itemCount = list.getCount();  
Log.i("recorded_file_delete", String.valueOf(itemCount)); 
for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){                  
    if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){                   
        boolean deleted = f.delete();
        if(deleted) {
            Asr.recordingsCache.removeRecordingFile(f);
            Log.i("recorded_file_delete", String.valueOf(deleted)); 
        }    
    }          
}
```

Comment: That method will not work if you use a custom row layout. But you have that boolean array, why don't you use that?

Comment: How can i use it?  By making it public?

Comment: You could make it public or expose it with a method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set item selected to be known to the listview as well. Try using this-
      `listView.setItemChecked(position,true);`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SparseBooleanArray arraySparse = myGridView.getcheckeditempositions();

for(int i=0;i<arraySparse.size();i++){
//Shows values boolean of keys 
     Log.d("MI_APP",""+arraySparce.valueAt(i));
//Shows keys id or position of your element in the GridView
     Log.d("MI_APP",""+arraySparce.keyAt(i));
}
```

Regards!